# Background image disappears on hover/mouseover and menu doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, background

I have 5 diffrent backgrounds which change from one to another when mouseover menu links like that:

[3 different screenshots out of 5](http://shrani.si/f/1R/Wx/JFACu4b/screenshot.jpg)

I want that the web site works properly in all browsers, but I get very different results. In firefox, background image dissapears and reappears on each menu link, but only first time when I go over a link with a cursor, other times works fine. In chrome backgrounds disappear and reappear on every onmouseover. And in IE onmouseover doesn't work at all nor the menu.

So I'm asking you to help me fix this, both things, dissapearing and the menu in IE. I found out that this disappearing and reappearing happens because of slow image loading, but I have no idea how to repair my code to fix this.

I just wrote my code in jsFiddle and menu doesn't work in it as well. And I noticed that when I downscale windows into the size smaller than div, the whole thing starts to deform. I thought I already fixed it, but it seems that I don't know how to that as well. You can see my code here:

[My Code in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MqBxN/)

**CSS**

```
body
{
    background-image:url(Slike/Ozadja/Osnova.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-attachment:local;
    background-color: #FFFAF0;
    background-size:794px;
}

#layoutWidth div
{
    width:628px;
    margin:auto;
    display:table;
    overflow:hidden;
}

div .header
{
    height:85px;
    text-align:center;
    display:table-row;
}

div .menu 
{
height:173px;
display:table-row;
}

#ddm
{   margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 30}

#ddm li
{   margin-left:12px;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    font: bold 100% arial}

#ddm li a
{   display: block;
    margin: 0 6px 0 0;
    padding: 4px 4px;
    width: 130px;
    background: transperent;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none}

#ddm li a:hover
{   background: transparent;
    color: #C0C0C0;
    }

#ddm div
{   position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding: 0;
    background: transparent;
    }


    #ddm  div a
    {   position: static;
        display: block;
        margin-left: -16px;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        width: 150px;
        white-space: normal;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: transperent;
        color: #000;
        font: bold 11px arial;
        }

    #ddm div a:hover
    {   background: transparent;
        color: #696969}

div .body
{   
    height:650px;
    text-align: left;
    display:table-row;
}

div .footer 
{   

    display:table-row;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Drop-Down Menu</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
    content="text/html;charset=UTF-16">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stil.css">

<!-- dd menu -->
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

var timeout         = 500;
var closetimer      = 0;
var ddmenuitem      = 0;
var myImage         = {};
myImage.m1 = 'Prvi_predal.png';
myImage.m2 = 'Drugi_predal.png';
myImage.m3 = 'Tretji_predal.png';
myImage.m4 = 'Cetrti_predal.png';

function mopen(id)
{   
    mcancelclosetime();

    if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';

    ddmenuitem = document.getElementById(id);
    ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(Slike/Ozadja/'+myImage[id]+')';
}


function mclose()
{
    if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(Slike/Ozadja/Osnova.png)'
}

function mclosetime()
{
    closetimer = window.setTimeout(mclose, timeout);
}

function mcancelclosetime()
{
    if(closetimer)
    {
        window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
        closetimer = null;
    }
}

document.onclick = mclose; 

// -->

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="layoutWidth">
<div class="header">
<a href="Domov.html">
<img src="Slike/Logo/Logo.png" alt="Mankajoč logotip" width="279" height="80"></a>
</div>



<div class="menu">
<ul id="ddm">
    <li><a href="#" onmouseover="mopen('m1')" onmouseout="mclosetime()">Obdelava lesa</a>
        <div id="m1" class="prvi" onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()" onmouseout="mclosetime()">
        <a href="#">Izdelki iz iverala</a>
        <a href="#">Izdelki iz masive</a>
        <a href="#">Obnova pohištva</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" onmouseover="mopen('m2')" onmouseout="mclosetime()">Talne obloge</a>
        <div id="m2" class="drugi" onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()" onmouseout="mclosetime()">
        <a href="#">Laminat</a>
        <a href="#">Parket</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" onmouseover="mopen('m3')" onmouseout="mclosetime()">Ostale storitve</a>
        <div id="m3" class="tretji" onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()" onmouseout="mclosetime()">
        <a href="#">Uporaba mavčnih plošč</a>
        <a href="#">Lažja zidarska dela</a>
        <a href="#">Fotografiranje dogodkov</a>
        <a href="#">Video zajem dogodkov</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" onmouseover="mopen('m4')" onmouseout="mclosetime()">Informacije</a>
        <div id="m4" class="cetrti" onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()" onmouseout="mclosetime()">
        <a href="#">O podjetju</a>
        <a href="#">Kontakt</a>
        <a href="#">Kje se nahajamo</a>
        <a href="#">Galerija</a>
        </div>
    </li>

</ul>
<div style="clear:both"></div>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>

<div class="body">
<p>Brez pomena.</p>
<br />
<p> Tole tudi! </p>
</div>

<div class="footer">
Brez pomena.
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what IE version you are using currently to run your program ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For blinking background images, and other images which you want to use from JS, you need to preload, or it will be blinking. How to preload an image? [Click here](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/image/preload.html)
(It's blinking, because when the page was loaded, the image wasn't. So, that image which you want to use, isn't at the user. The browser download it, but until that time, theres no image what it can show for him/her. This is the reason.)

IE is blocking JS in default (like IE 10). You need to enable it. I've got a warning bubble an the bottom, which say, I've blocking everything... or something like that. You can't enable this from script. Only you can create a warning message for the user, which you remove if JS is enabled.

An extra thing, in jsFiddle it will work the page if you select the "no warp - in `<head>`" option from the second drop down list at top left. After that you need to click run at top.

Comment: Can I ask you how should I integrate option 1 from link you provided in my current code?

Comment: put that `if` after `document.onclick = mclose;` event

Comment: Man, I feel so stupid to ask you this, but could you please show me what to do. If you could just write it in my jsFiddle code and post the link, I would be forever grateful. I did what you said, but obviously I would have to change img tag to something else, but I don't know what. I tryed to change it to myImage or myImage.m1, myImage.m2.. but it doesn't work. I just don't get it, my knowledge of JS sucks.

Comment: sorry for the delayed response, here is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/MqBxN/3/